# Is there a way to merge two dataframes by a mathematical operation in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I a working on a little R project.

Given two data frames with different length:

```
df1 = data.frame(Plane.Id = c(19924519, 19924321, 19992436, 19924119, 19924208, 19924330), 
                 Block.ID = c(090LC, 090LC, 001UG, 002LM, 001OI, 001UG), 
                 Hour1 = c(0.02222222, 0.02222222, 15.07222, 15.44444, 6.652778, 3.286111))

df2 = data.frame(Block.Id = c(090LC, 001UG, 001UG, 002LM, 001OI), 
                 Sector.ID = c(BIRDFIS, UKOVS, LLLLALL, EBBUEHS, LEBLDDN), 
                 Hour_In = c(0.000000, 0.000000, 13.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000), 
                 Hour_Out = c(23.50000, 13.000000, 23.50000, 23.50000, 23.50000))
```

Different Sector.ID are assigned to the same Block.ID depending on the hour of the day.

Is it possible to merge them into a single dataframe following the next conditions?:

- If the Block.ID column value from both dataframes is the same
- If the Hour1 value from df1 is between the Hour_In and Hour_Out from df2 (Hour_in <= Hour1 <= Hour_Out)

What I am looking for is a dataframe with the lenght of df1 that contains the data Plane.ID, Block.ID and Sector.ID. Something like this (I do not know how to build a table in here, so I uploaded an image with the table):

**df_final**

[image]

I have tried with rbind, left_join, merge, cbind and nothing good came out. I even tried to do this with a loop but not a good idea.

Comment: at a glance it sounds like you want a non-equi join from data.table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[df2, on = .(Block.ID, Hour1 >= Hour_In, Hour1 <= Hour_Out), .(Plane.Id, Block.ID, Sector.ID)]
```

**Output**

```
   Plane.Id Block.ID Sector.ID
1: 19924519    090LC   BIRDFIS
2: 19924321    090LC   BIRDFIS
3: 19924330    001UG     UKOVS
4: 19992436    001UG   LLLLALL
5: 19924119    002LM   EBBUEHS
6: 19924208    001OI   LEBLDDN
```

Answer (score 0):

How about inner joining on the "Block_id" and filtering by the "Hour1" using `dplyr`?

```
df1 = 
  data.frame(
    Plane.Id = c(19924519, 19924321, 19992436, 19924119, 19924208, 19924330), 
    Block.ID = c("090LC", "090LC", "001UG", "002LM", "001OI", "001UG"), 
    Hour1    = c(0.02222222, 0.02222222, 15.07222, 15.44444, 6.652778, 3.286111)
  )

df2 = data.frame(
  Block.ID = c("090LC", "001UG", "001UG", "002LM", "001OI"), 
  Sector.ID = c("BIRDFIS", "UKOVS", "LLLLALL", "EBBUEHS", "LEBLDDN"), 
  Hour_In = c(0.000000, 0.000000, 13.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000), 
  Hour_Out = c(23.50000, 13.000000, 23.50000, 23.50000, 23.50000)
)

dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by="Block.ID") %>%
dplyr::filter(Hour1 > Hour_In & Hour1 < Hour_Out)
```